# How to save time without date in shapefile's DATE filed using ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, time, date

I am trying to save a time in a shapefile's DATE field (without a date, because shapefile can only store something one simultaneously - date or time).

I use field calculator with PYTHON parser. I am typing a string `'12:01:51'`. After pushing OK button it seems all right - no error, but the value turns to 0:00:00.

What do i do wrong?

[image]

Comment: I could reproduce your error. This seems to be a bug since the documentation says it's possible. But why don't you use a feature class?

Comment: @GeoGE: Idle curiosity, without ArcView knowlege:  With a shapefile that has a field which is a Date/Time field, can one feature/dataPoint/Row contain a date, and  another dataPoint contain a time?  I ask, wondering if the date/time choice is by file, rather than dataPoint, and then wondering if once the choice is made for the file, it is a fixed choice, and...then...wondering if you set a field to date on first use of the file's date/time field...

Comment: @John Yes you can do that, doesn't seem to be convenient to manage/query etc at first sight but why not? Field values for one row don't influence values for other rows. But there seems to be a bug with shapefiles so you could only use dates anyway (use a feature class instead).

Comment: I send request to support. Will see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got support's answer. They said it is well known issue and quote from this [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005600000013000000) is wrong:

> Date fields support either the date or the time, but not both in the same field.

Document will be changed soon.

Also they said that I could use `text` field for time values in shape file.